# Open Visual Studio Crystal Reports Wizard for created RPT files

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, crystal-reports, wizard

I'm using Crystal Reports (v 13.0) Wizard to create some RPT reports.

When I add a new .rpt, VS start with the Wizard. Then when the Wizard procedure ends it generates the .rpt file.

I want to know if it is possible to open again the created .rpt file with the Wizard showing the settings I made before, to be able to change them.

If I double click the .rpt file it opens inside the Report view like this:

[image: Report View]

I tried with right click on the .rpt and the .cs but I found no options like "Open with Wizard..." or so. Is it possible?

Comment: "right click on the .rpt and the .cs but I found no options" , can you explain more about it?

Comment: No options like "Open with Wizard" or similar.

Comment: Please explain more about your question

Comment: which type of setting you want to do with wizard?bcz there is only possible to work with database expert after creating report

Comment: @VidhiTrivedi: If possible I'd like to re-run the Wizard... so I can change any setting. But otherwise what can I change and how?

Comment: right click on your rpt file then Design -> Default Setting -> you can change setting that you want to do

Comment: Design -> Default Settings... is not what I was looking for. Anyway your hint was right! With right click on the report in design mode there are many options in the context menu: Database Expert..., Selection Expert... and so on. Thank you! If you want to add an answer I'll close the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With **right click** on the report in design mode there are many options in the context menu: **Database Expert...**, **Selection Expert...** and so on.